# don't correct out put in C#

Tags: c#

example I enter 1357 and program out 106 instead of 10

```
        string num = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write(Convert.ToInt32(num[1]) + Convert.ToInt32(num[3]));
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: why would it do that? use a debugger to check the runtime values of the string, the chars, and the conversion results. hint: `Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(num[1]));` is 51, the ascii codepoint of 3

Comment: You're adding the integer values of the backing characters for "3" and "7" which are 51 and 55, respectively. You want to add the parsed values of those characters.

Comment: I want 10 as output , num[1] = 3 , num[3] = 7;

Comment: yes, but observe that `num[1] = '3'`, not `3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert the single characters to a string before converting to integer. Convert will use the Unicode code point value when converting char to integer directly.

```
var value = Convert.ToInt32(num[1].ToString()) + Convert.ToInt32(num[3].ToString());
```

Comment: Good explanation of what is going on.